# Matlab spectrograms giving imaginary-like numbers

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, fft, spectrogram

I'm using MATLAB to work with some spectrograms. I'm new to this kind of thing and come from more of a CS background than a signals background, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here although it may turn out to be fairly basic.

I'm trying to compute spectral difference, which I conceptually am pretty sure I understand. I've got a signal, I can do the SFT on it with MATLAB's spectrogram() function. Then, I try to loop over the spectrogram for the entire signal and at each sampled point compute the difference from the previous point by looping over powers at each frequency and subtracting. I thought I had the concept down, but when I try to run it, I realize that the points returned when I write "MySpectrogram(n,k)" are complex numbers, or atleast look like that. They are formed such that the first part of the number is negative, and then after it there is a +Coefficient*I (-.07+0.0061i) for example. I tried to square these results. After squaring them, they still appear as complex numbers. Now I am totally lost. Can someone explain what's happening?

I'm calling s = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft).

Comment: The Fourier transform is a complex-valued function. That is, the output of `spectrogram` is a series of complex values. MATLAB shows these as `<real>+<imag>i`. Squaring a complex number does not make it real. Use `abs` if you want to use only the magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for [spectrogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)

If you need to access the power spectrum, use this:

```
[s,f,t,ps] = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,f,fs)
```